# Bootstrapping an ordinal logistic regression using R

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap, ordinal-data

As one of my IV does not meet the assumptions of a ordinal logistic regression model (the fit of the model itself is pretty good though R^2 = .52), I wanted to use bootstrapping in order to "secure" my findings. However, no matter what I do, there are errors...
My AV is a ordinal variable with three levels.
I tried different versions of the function. This is the one which seems right "the most". Maybe somebody can help?!?

```r
# Anzahl der gewünschten Boot Samples
B <- 5000

# Funktion, die das Sample generiert

boot.polr <- function(dataIn, indices, maxit=20){
  data <- dataIn[indices,]
  mod <- polr(BB.f ~ Pathologisierung + Pat.f + Form.f + F60.f, 
           data = data, Hess = TRUE)
  coefficients(mod)
}

# Parametric bootstrap

bootstrap <- boot(dat2, boot.polr, B)
```

```r
Fehler in optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...) : 
  Anfangswert in 'vmmin' ist nicht endlich
```

That is German and means the starting value is not finite. How can I help R to find the correct starting value?!

Comment: What assumption is violated?

Comment: What is your purpose in using the bootstrap?  What do you mean by "secure"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user hasn't responded to the comments and hasn't been on the site in years.